# Error during Installation of Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 22.04, bootloader, usb-installation, squashfs

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 with a bootable USB, but after the Ubuntu logo it shows me the following error.
Something related to `Failed to start set console scheme` `SQUASHFS error`

[image: Full error message]

Comment: Seems like a bad install media. Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO, then if offered the install media?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)